# Converting decode utf-8 string to file

Tags: java

I am trying to save image which I am receiving from android device. From Android getting utf-8 encode string and below is the code I am using to save.

```
String test = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(image_base64, "UTF-8");
byte[] data = Base64.decodeBase64(test.getBytes());
FileOutputStream stream = null;

try {
    stream = new FileOutputStream("/var/lib/easy-tomcat7/webapps/test/test1.bmp");
    stream.write(data);
    stream.flush();
    test1 += "success";
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    test1 = "failuare";
    e.getMessage();
}
finally
{
    test1 += "finally";
    stream.close();
}
```

File is creating but the it is corrupted. I did lot of research on this but not getting why it is happening. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: e.getMessage() doesn't do anything. Did you mean System.err.println(e.getMessage())? Or perhaps even e.printStackTrace()?

Comment: @David I have just written that line.. since it is not reaching catch block. I think it doesn't matter

Comment: I have tested in online converter the utf-8 decode string is correct ...but after that data is not writing properly to the file

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using `Base64` from [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/).

Note that you are dealing with multiple different kinds of encodings:

- [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)
- [Base64 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)
- [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) character encoding

Those are three totally different things, and you should understand all of them to understand what is happening exactly.

Check how exactly the image is encoded that you get from the Android device. Your code is assuming that you are getting it as URL-encoded Base64 data, using the UTF-8 character set. Is that indeed how the Android device is sending the data? You will have to check that with whoever wrote the Android application.

What does the string `image_base64` contain? Is it valid, URL-encoded Base64 data?

You shouldn't call `getBytes()` on the string before you pass it to `Base64.decodeBase64` - that will convert the string into a byte array using the default character encoding of the system you're running it on. Just do this instead:

```
byte[] data = Base64.decodeBase64(test);
```

To make matters worse, there are several variants of Base64 encoding (as you can see on the Wikipedia page about [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)). It may be the case that whatever variant the Android app used is different from what the `Base64` class is using.

Comment: image_base64 is valid string, I have checked in online converter and I tried byte[] data = Base64.decodeBase64(test); this also , but still same problem corrupted file. How can I fix this ?please help me

Comment: to be more specific in android using

Answer (score 1):

Use the encoding also for  getBytes()

```
Base64.decodeBase64(test.getBytes("utf-8"));
```